# jQuery anonymous functions - nesting functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

Recently I've been getting into Anonymous functions in a big way and wondering how this is possible as I'm trying to re-arrange my JS code-base.

```
(function (listLoad, $, undefined) {
    listLoad.create = function(data)
    {
        this.init = function(data)
        {
        }
    } 
} (window.listLoad = window.listLoad || {}, jQuery));
```

What I'm looking to do is obviously have a number of functions for my "listLoad" page, such as "dataMap" etc, in which will all have init functions for initializing the page.

My main question is how do I access this .init function? I'm guessing it's of private scope. I've tried:

```
listLoad.create.init = function(data)
```

and

```
 create.init = function(data)
```

and even `init = function(data)`

All to no success when writing

```
listLoad.create.init();
```

How to do this? I'm more than happy to hear certain suggestions on architecture too if you feel I'm going the wrong way about my scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact your syntax for anonymous function is not complete.

First you must execute the annonymous block with ending parentheses:

```
(function (...) {
    ...
})(...)
```

Inside the block, your code could be improved this way:

```
var listLoad = {};

(function (x) {
    x.create = {
        init: function(data) {
            console.log('plop');
        }
    }
})(listLoad);


listLoad.create.init()
```

This provoke plop to appear logged into the console.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you! For reference, my anon function was executing, but I needed to change the syntax to 

listLoad.create = { init: function(data) { } }

Once again, thank you!